# How to access Sql table with schema in Cake PHP

Tags: sql-server-2008, cakephp, schema

I am doing a cake php Project Integrated with SQL server 2008. But I not able to access the schema tables in CAKE PHP. Can anybody help me please...

Comment: What's your code? How have you attempted to get the schema?

Comment: I have created plugin for accessing SQL server 2008. But it connect with normal tables only(dbo schema).But now i want to Connect with user defined Schema tables

Answer (score 0):

in your model with

```
$this->schema();
```